# Count instances per date on Joint table

Tags: sql, presto

Assume I have two tables: `Dates` and `Actions`.

I would like to count how many actions were present against all dates selected for the `Dates` table.

I am pulling my dates table like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dateid
FROM
    dates
WHERE 
    DATE(dateid) BETWEEN DATE('2019-01-01') and CURRENT_DATE
```

On my `Actions` table, I have field `action_date`. i would like to count how many times an `action_date` is present from `dates`

---

Date table generated by query above

```
+-------+
| Dateid|
+-------+
| Jan 1 |
+-------+
| Jan 2 |
+-------+
| Jan 3 |
+-------+
| Jan 4 |
+-------+
```

---

Table of actions by date

```
+-------------+
| Action_Date |
+-------------+
| Jan 1       |
+-------------+
| Jan 1       |
+-------------+
| Jan 1       |
+-------------+
| Jan 2       |
+-------------+
| Jan 3       |
+-------------+
| Jan 3       |
+-------------+
| Jan 3       |
+-------------+
| Jan 3       |
+-------------+
```

---

Desired output

```
+-------------+-------+
| Action_Date | Count |
+-------------+-------+
| Jan 1       | 3     |
+-------------+-------+
| Jan 2       | 1     |
+-------------+-------+
| Jan 3       | 4     |
+-------------+-------+
| Jan 4       | 0     |
+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, COUNT(*).

Comment: @jarlh i don't know how to use a COUNT(*) when joining. Do I join a sub query where the sub query is a count by date? It's really the order of operations that has me lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `left join`:

```
SELECT d.dateid as ActionDate, COUNT(a.ActionDate)
FROM Dates d LEFT JOIN
     Actions a 
     ON a.ActionDate = dt.dateid
WHERE DATE(dateid) BETWEEN DATE('2019-01-01') AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY d.dateid
ORDER BY DATE(d.dateid);
```

Answer (score 1):

(Table names and column names may need to be adjusted)

```
SELECT a.ActionDate, COUNT(*)
FROM Action_Date a JOIN DateTable dt ON a.ActionDate = dt.dateid
GROUP BY a.ActionDate
```